# passing variables in python through functions unicode error

Tags: python

code :

```
def power(base,exponent):  
  result = base**exponent
  print "%d to the power of %d is %d." % (base, exponent, result)

n=raw_input("Enter a number whose power you wish to calculate:")
p=raw_input("Enter the power:")
power(n,p)
```

Some unicode error is coming while executing please help

Comment: You need to convert the input to integers: `int(raw_input("..."))`

Comment: Also, please *always* put the error message into your question.

Comment: you can either use `int(raw_input())` or simply `input()`

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returning string. You have to convert it to integer, because your function  finding power of a number.

```
def power(base,exponent):  
    result = base**exponent
    print "%d to the power of %d is %d." % (base, exponent, result)

n=int(raw_input("Enter a number whose power you wish to calculate:"))
p=int(raw_input("Enter the power:"))
power(n,p)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this to make sure you don't get error on inserting non digits:

```
def power(base,exponent):  
    result = base**exponent
    print "%d to the power of %d is %d." % (base, exponent, result)

def int_input(message):
    input_value = raw_input(message)
    if input_value.isdigit():
        return int(input_value)
    print "This is not a Number."
    return int_input(message)

n = int_input("Enter a number whose power you wish to calculate:")
p = int_input("Enter the power:")
power(n, p)
```